How to properly escape single quotes in filenames?
I have files with single quotes in their name, say o'a. I want to process them in awk (gawk-5.3.0):
(fd is an alternative to find).
Please don't tell me about fd -x option, my command is snippet of a larger one and I am really interested in the awk solution.
fd . | awk '{ print "name: \047" $0 "\047"; cmd="stat -c \"%U\" " $0 ; cmd | getline result ; print result }'

and I get errors:
name: 'o'a'
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

How to properly escape the quotes in the name in awk ? I tried with gsub but nothing has worked so far.
There are also files with $ sign, so the best solution would be to sanitize names for most of worse situations which of course will occur!

@jonrsharpe why have removed awk in title? this question is really about some (g)awk intricacies.

Can you show output of fd .

https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

@anubhava fd . produces o'a. I use more options like fd . -tf -a to get fullpath and only files, but that's not the point here!

Just like GNU find, fd has a -0 option to unambiguously separate file names with arbitrary characters in their names.
Unfortunately, Awk can't really cope with null-terminated input, though GNU Awk allegedly should be fine with it. Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Your case would probably make more sense with fd . -x stat with some sensible options to decorate the output. The complication is that calling another command from Awk doesn't really let you quote arbitrary quote characters etc.

@triplee thanks, but I anticipated this remark and I wrote 'Please don't tell me about fd -x option' as I have a few command and I am interested in awk solution that puzzled me all day ;-) !

Why is Awk a requirement though? This would be quite easy with Perl or Python.

@triplee why not gawk? I set it up like that and thought it would be simple :-) I don't use Perl anyway.

If you don't want to use fd -x because your "command is snippet of a larger one" did you realize that sh -c 'CMD' _ {} is also a command that you can pass to fd -x, and that CMD can be anything from simple commands (stat ...) to a shell function call (foobar) or a shell script (/opt/super-complicated) or anything else that the shell can execute? (replace sh with bash, python, or anything else if you prefer that).

@RenaudPacalet Thanks for completing my question. No I didn't really know! I am still struggling with file names containing single quotes and dollar sign, and sometimes both (no choice but to keep them as is). Shouldn't the command be fd -x sh -c 'CMD  {}'? I don't understand yours sh -c 'CMD' _ {} (which will not work with the stupid file names anyway, right ?).

It should work with any file name, with any character in it (quotes, dollar signs, newlines...) I do not have fd here but you can try fd . -x sh -c 'printf "name: %s\n" "$1"; stat -c "%U" "$1"' _ {} \; for the example processing you mention in your question. Note that the awk-based solutions could fail if your file names contain newline characters. So, they are not only more complicated and less elegant, but also maybe less robust.

I added an answer with some explanations.

The shell does not interpret contents of single-quoted strings.
The only unacceptable character in a single-quoted string is single-quote.
Standalone single-quotes can be safely passed to the shell if escaped by a backslash.
So:
fd . | awk -v q=\' '
    function enquote(unsafe,    s){
        s = unsafe
        gsub(q, "&\\\\&&", s)
        return q s q
    }
    {
        print "name: " q $0 q
        cmd = "stat -c %U " enquote($0)
        cmd | getline
        print
        close(cmd)
    }
'


or maybe: ... | awk ... -v eq=\''\\'\'\' ' ... gsub(q,eq,s) ...'

Thank you. I couldn't have found this solution by myself! there is the awk-ism I learnt laterly, the spaces before s in enquote(unsafe,     s)  added for readability if not wrong, the & I didn't know about in gsub. And I was already bitten by the \' which is surprisingly not escaped at all in awk quoted body. Awk is tricky for beginners !

@jgran glad it was helpful. I would be surprised if this question isn't a duplicate although I can't find one - but I have just found https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64218/333919

yes, the spaces are a convention to help the reader distinguish expected parameters from those being used as local variables. I don't think awk cares. eg: awk 'function f(a,b){printf "(%s)(%s)\n",a,b} BEGIN{f(1);f(1,2)}'

Note that this will fail if file names contain newline characters.

@RenaudPacalet yes, I'd have suggested something like your answer if the question hadn't explicitly told me not to :-/

#jhnc Yep, this was an X-Y problem, I guess.

@jhnc yes sorry, my question was really an awk question, for making a little progress with it.  I didn't want to be redirected to another solution and stay with my awk question which surprised me. I didn't know how to put my question in a better way, as SOF curators are sometimes quick downvoters! Everybody was very nice and very helpful. A very good SOF experience!

and as a side effect, I have learnt about X-Y Problem.

Just like GNU find, fd has a -0 option to unambiguously separate file names with arbitrary characters in their names. Some Awk variants can't cope with null-terminated input as that's not a valid text file per POSIX, though GNU Awk and yet others are fine with it (read the man page for your awk); but then successfully passing it to a subprocess with correct quoting gets complex, too.
However, this would be quite easy with Perl or Python.
fd -0 . |
perl -0 -ne '
    print("name: \047$_\047\n");
    system("stat", "-c", "\"%U\"", $_);'

Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

If the reason for not using fd -x is that you think it is limited to simple commands then you should probably reconsider. The command you pass to fd -x (or find -exec) can be anything like a shell or python script, a shell function... With your own example you could try:
fd . -x sh -c 'printf "name: \x27%s\x27\n" "$1"; stat -c "%U" "$1"' _ {}

From the sh manual:

sh -c command_string [command_name [argument ...]]
...
Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input. Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.) set from the remaining argument operands.

In our case command_name could be anything, we don't use argument $0. I use _ because it is a "don't care" for me. There is only one argument, the {} placeholder that fd replaces with the name of the found file. Note that it is optional because fd adds it by default. I used it for clarity. The script is simple; all "$1" are substituted with the first command argument. As long as you don't forget to double-quote it, there is no need to pay attention to special characters, quotes, dollars, newlines or anything, it should work with any file name, with any character in it.
Note that the awk-based solutions will fail if your file names contain newline characters. So, they are not only more complicated and less elegant, but also less robust.
Of course, if your script is more complicated you can define a shell function or put it in a file. Example with bash and a function:
foo() {
  printf "name: '%s'\n" "$1"
  stat -c "%U" "$1"
}
export -f foo
fd . -x bash -c 'foo "$1"' _ {}

Edit: jhnc noted in comments that "fd|cmd feeds all files into a single command. fd -x cmd invokes the command multiple times with batches of the files". This is true. But:

fd runs the commands in parallel (up to the number of CPU cores or NJOBS if the -j NJOBS option is used).
fd also has a -X option (see below) to pass several found files at once to the command.
The solutions based on awk also spawn one shell per input line. On a performance point of view fd -x should be better than awk in most if not all cases.

If you have performance issues because the number of files to process is large you can play with the -j NJOBS option or use the -X option, instead of -x, or both:
foo() {
  for f in "$@"; do
    printf "name: '%s'\n" "$f"
    stat -c "%U" "$f"
  done
}
export -f foo
fd . -j 8 --batch-size 100 -X bash -c 'foo "$@"' _ {}

This will run up to 8 jobs in parallel and, in each job, pass up to 100 file names at once to function foo instead of just one with option -x. Of course, if the script calls external commands (like stat), the benefit will not be that big because a child process will be spawned anyway for each file.
Note that finding the best combination of -j NJOBS (maximum number of parallel jobs) and --batch-size SIZE (maximum number of files per command invocation) may require some profiling. Note also that there is a maximum length of shell commands. If fd does not manage this automatically (I could not find this information in the manual), and the file names are long and/or SIZE is too large you could hit the wall...

THANK YOU very much for the deepening of my question and reading in my mind! As a matter of fact, I almost wrote your solution, but did a wrong fd . -x bash -c 'foo {}'. I tried to quote '{}'... Where did you find the syntax   fd . -x bash -c 'foo "$1"' _ {}?

You're welcome. No, I did not read in your mind, but your question had a "X-Y problem" flavor, so... For fd -x, man fd tells you everything. And man sh (or man bash, man dash) tells you everything about sh -c. The only trick with the bash function is that it must be exported (export -f foo) such that it is passed to the environment of children processes.

I work on Windows mainly, but I use many Rust portable tools. I don't have the reflex to use man sadly. I read https://github.com/sharkdp/fd, and didn't see the syntax _ {} mentionned.

Oh, sorry, I see. In fd manual you learn about {} (in the section about the -x) option. But not about _ {} because this _, as I explain, is just an artifact. We need something for the command_name in a sh -c ... command. So why not _? You can replace with my_nice_script if you wish.

Thanks again. It's quite clear now. And beside all, your solution using only fd . -x bash -c 'foo "$1"' _ {} is the simplest and the fastest one. I also learnt a bit more about awk on the way, which might be useful. I would accept this answer as a solution but I built up my question around awk, so the answer is a bit off topics relative to the question though highly relevant.

Good to know that you learned something useful. And you're right to not accept this answer, it is not an answer to your initial question about awk and quoting. Accepting it would puzzle future readers. The one you accepted is perfect, mine is just a complement.

There is actually a difference that can be significant in certain cases: fd|cmd feeds all files into a single command. fd -x cmd invokes the command multiple times with batches of the files

@jhnc If you mean fd -x cmd runs as many commands as there are found files, you're right. But 1) fd runs the commands in parallel (up to the number of CPU cores or the -j option), 2) fd also has a -X option (I will add this in my answer) and 3) the solutions based on awk also spawn one shell per input line. On a performance point of view fd -x should be better than awk in most if not all cases.

I was actually conflating with find (I haven't used fd) but same principle - all: find / | wc -l vs batch: find / -exec sh -c 'echo $#' - {} +

the difference could be important if global knowledge is required (perhaps command is an awk script that builds a lookup table from the files)

Ah, I see, sorry I misunderstood your comment. The -x option of fd has no + variant like the -exec option of find. Instead it has a -X option that takes several file names at once. And yes, if a global knowledge is needed piping, would be better. But that's not something we can conclude from the OP. Plus, file names with embedded newlines would be an issue.

@RenaudPacalet : i'm curious as to who or what actually creates filenames nowadays with newlines other than software that's hostile and nefarious by design, like ransomware

@RAREKpopManifesto Interesting research project. I don't have the budget for it but I would also be interested. GUIs? Badly designed scripts? People who also put white spaces, tabs, etc. in their file names and don't see why they shouldn't? People who do exactly what ChatGPT suggested? Reptilians?

@RenaudPacalet : that's why i specifically said "newlines" only. Spaces are perfectly reasonable to be in filenames, tabs somewhat marginal, but newlines are the truly whacko bunch.

@RenaudPacalet : as for "badly designed scripts" - if the scripts were that callously designed to begin with, then more likely than not, other scripts further downstream in the execution chain likely would also mishandle newlines in filenames. If historical wrongs were always left in place "because it has always been done that way", then slavery would have never been abolished.

As usual the fundamental question is not how reasonable or frequent it is to have newlines in filenames. It is: do we propose solutions that can break or not? My personal position (you don't have to agree) is that not knowing who will read these Q&A and what they will do with them, I prefer trying to provide solutions that cannot break, even with low probability. And I am not saying that I always succeed. Just trying.

You got the answer to your question but FYI it's very rare for what you're doing to be the right approach because you have this hierarchy of calls:
shell {
    awk {
        for (each input line) {
            subshell {
                stat
            }
        }
    }
}

which is very inefficient as it's spawning a new subshell to call stat once per input line. If, instead of shell calling awk to call shell to call stat, you just have shell call stat directly:
shell {
    for (each input line) {
        stat
    }
}

then you're obviously spawning far fewer processes so it's more efficient and it's easier to handle any characters in the file names because it's using the shell for it's intended purpose (creating/destroying files and processes and sequencing calls to tools) and using awk just for it's intended purpose (manipulating text), instead of trying to make awk also do shells job.
So, assuming you have more you want to do in awk, consider doing something like this instead of calling stat from awk (use xargs instead of a loop if convenient):
fd . |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    stat -c '%U' "$line"
done |
awk 'whatever'

and there are various ways to handle mixing the output stream from the stat calls with whatever else you need awk to do with any other input, ask a new question if you need help with that.
